# Lost in callback hell with Node, Express and google Analytics API

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm a beginner here so I'll try to expose my issue the best way I can. I'm trying to call the Google Analytics API on the server-side to show some data on the client-side with react and d3. Here is my script to call the GA api :

```
var google = require ("googleapis");
var key = require ('./client_id.json');

const VIEW_ID = 'ga:80820965';

let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  key.client_email, 
  null,
  key.private_key,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'],
  null
);

    jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      let analytics = google.analytics('v3');
        queryData(analytics);
    });

var queryData = function(analytics) {
      analytics.data.ga.get({
        'auth': jwtClient,
        'ids': VIEW_ID,
        'metrics': 'ga:uniquePageviews',
        'dimensions': 'ga:pagePath',
        'start-date': '30daysAgo',
        'end-date': 'yesterday',
        'sort': '-ga:uniquePageviews',
        'max-results': 10,
      }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
      });  
    }


module.exports = {
    queryData
};
```

When I calling this script independently everything is fine, however when I'm calling it with my whole project I've got the following error :

```
[1]   analytics.data.ga.get({
[1]            ^
[1] 
[1] TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

From what I have understand `data` is undefined because `analytics` is undefined. And `analytics` is undefined because this call :

```
   jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      let analytics = google.analytics('v3');
        data = queryData(analytics);
    });
```

is an async call. I guess the time the client_id is loaded.

So how can I write this script so that `queryData` is running only when this part :

```
let analytics = google.analytics('v3');
        data = queryData(analytics);
```

is ready ?

I hope my issue is clear and make sense to you. I've read about async/await module. However I'm not enable to use it my self.

Edit #1 : I need to use something like this but I'm not sure how

```
module.exports = {queryData: function (err, req, res, next) { next(); }};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're defining `analytics` as a local variable here:

```
jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  let analytics = google.analytics('v3');
    queryData(analytics);
});
```

And then expecting it to be available here in `queryData(analytics)` in your export.

What you can do instead is resolve your `authorize` call in a promise (since there will be a race condition when it first initializes, so you can wrap it in a promise and wait for it to resolve before being able to call `queryData`). Something like this:

```
var google = require ("googleapis");
var key = require ('./client_id.json');
const Promise = require('bluebird');
var authorizationPromise;

const VIEW_ID = 'ga:80820965';

let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  key.client_email, 
  null,
  key.private_key,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'],
  null
);

authorizationPromise = Promise.promisify(jwtClient.authorize)()
.then(function (err, tokens) {
  if (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }

  return google.analytics('v3');
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});

var queryData = function() {
  authorizationPromise.then(function(analytics) {
      analytics.data.ga.get({
        'auth': jwtClient,
        'ids': VIEW_ID,
        'metrics': 'ga:uniquePageviews',
        'dimensions': 'ga:pagePath',
        'start-date': '30daysAgo',
        'end-date': 'yesterday',
        'sort': '-ga:uniquePageviews',
        'max-results': 10,
      }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
      }); 
  });
};

module.exports = {
    queryData
};
```

I'm not sure off-hand whether `jwtClient.authorize` provides a promise API, so I just "promisified" it using [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I really understand my issue now. however I've tried your code and got the following error `Cannot read property 'refreshToken_' of undefined`, any idea where is that come from ?

Comment: @SimonBreton, No problem. I don't know, I haven't tested the above code. I just implemented a pretty common pattern for this type of situation, but you might have to go through the stack trace and investigate where that error is coming from. Sorry I couldn't be of more help. Let me know if you have any other questions as you proceed...

Comment: can you give me a little more detail about the `authorizationPromise` code. I especially don't understand the use of the `tokens` variable. thanks.